# Postgres: select for update using CTE

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

I always had a query in the form of:

```
UPDATE 
  users 
SET 
  col = 1 
WHERE 
  user_id IN ( 
    SELECT 
      user_id 
    FROM 
      users 
    WHERE 
      ... 
    LIMIT 1
    FOR UPDATE 
  );
```

And I was pretty sure that it generates a lock on the affected row until the update is done.

Now I wrote the same query using CTE and doing

```
WITH query AS (
  select 
    user_id 
  FROM 
    users 
  WHERE 
    ... 
  LIMIT 1 
  FOR UPDATE 
)
UPDATE 
  users 
SET 
  col = 1 
WHERE 
  user_id IN ( 
    SELECT 
      user_id 
    FROM 
      query 
  );
```

I’m actually having some doubts that it is applying a row lock because of the results I get, but I couldn’t find anything documented about this.

Can someone make it clear? Thanks

Edit:

I managed to find this:

If specific tables are named in FOR UPDATE or FOR SHARE, then only rows coming from those tables are locked; any other tables used in the SELECT are simply read as usual. A FOR UPDATE or FOR SHARE clause without a table list affects all tables used in the statement. If FOR UPDATE or FOR SHARE is applied to a view or sub-query, it affects all tables used in the view or sub-query. However, FOR UPDATE/FOR SHARE do not apply to WITH queries referenced by the primary query. If you want row locking to occur within a WITH query, specify FOR UPDATE or FOR SHARE within the WITH query.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE

So I guess it should work only if the for update is in the with and not in the query that is using the with?